# How do I do this deployment by command line

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I can do a deploy like this, but cannot do it via command line.

[image]

I was looking at doing it like this

```
kubectl create -f kubernetes-rc.json
```

---

```
{
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "foo-frontend-rc",
    "labels": {
      "www": true
    },
    "namespace": "foo"
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "app": "foo-frontend"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "foo-frontend",
            "image": "gcr.io/atomic-griffin-130023/foo-frontend:b3fc862",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 3009,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

and

```
kubectl create -f kubernetes-service.json
```

---

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "foo-frontend-service"
  },
  "spec": {
    "selector": {
      "app": "foo-frontend-rc"
    },
    "ports": [
      {
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": 3009
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

to no avail. It creates the `rc`, but it won’t expose the service externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service's selector is wrong. It should be selecting a label from the pod template, not a label on the RC itself.

If you change the following in your service:

```
"selector": {
  "app": "foo-frontend-rc"
},
```

to:

```
"selector": {
  "app": "foo-frontend"
},
```

It should fix it.

---

### Update

Change your service definition to

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "foo-frontend-service"
  },
  "spec": {
    "selector": {
      "app": "foo-frontend"
    },
    "ports": [
      {
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": 3009,
        "nodePort": 30009
      }
    ],
    "type": "LoadBalancer"
  }
}
```

Comment: Now it has the internal endpoint, but no external. See http://f.cl.ly/items/3p1h251j29213l1Z2F0Y/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-05%20at%205.34.55%20PM.png

Comment: To expose it externally you must set the service `type` to either `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` and then specify a `nodePort` value in the `ports` section.

Take a look here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#publishing-services---service-types